# The use of "une Cata"

Tags: traduction

I just saw the following [Tweet](https://twitter.com/NoraHamadi/status/1179810742280826883) in French about the MEP Magid Magid.

"Le Swag du depute Magid Magid @MagicMagid au Parlement europeen est sans doute une des raisons pour lesquelles le Brexit est une Cata. Tellement rafraichissant de voir des élus qui nous ressemblent !"

I'm translating that as saying his dress sense is refreshing because it is good to see those who have been elected resemble the public.  However, I'm a bit confused by the "est sans doute une des raisons pour lesquelles le Brexit est une Cata", as this then seems to condtradict it by blaming his clothes for Brexit being a catastrophe.  I'm wondering if Cata with a capital C can mean something different?

Comment: I'd say the capital C is just either a typing error or the person wanted to emphasize it is a huge catastrophe. Most probably no more to it.

Comment: But then it contradicts the next sentence, doesn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a contradiction only because you're melding the 2 sentences as if they were in the same register.

"The getup of MP Magid Magid in the European Parliament is without a doubt one of the reasons why Brexit is such a disaster.  So refreshing to see elected officials who look like us!"

The second sentence is entirely sarcastic, don't try to fold it in to the other.  Whether you agree with the opinion or not :-)

Comment: That makes sense.  I saw it when Magid retweeted it, so I assume he also missed any sarcasm intended!